# MySQL Query to combine these tables correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have two large tables, as follows:

First Table:

```
tbl_properties
    id
    address
    city
    state
    zip
    timestamp
```

Second Table:

```
tbl_units
    id
    propertyID (relates the unit to a property)
    unitName
    timestamp
```

I am trying to create a list of all properties *without* units, AND all units (aligned with its property).

So for an example, if I have:

PROPERTIES:

- 1234 Ashton Lane San Fran, CA 90001
- 6485 Johnson Lane San Fran, CA 54678

  UNITS:
- 1A (part of 1234 Ashton)
- 1B (part of 1234 Ashton)
- 1C (part of 1234 Ashton)

Then the query will create the following:

- 1234 Ashton Lane San Fran, CA 90001 - Unit 1A
- 1234 Ashton Lane San Fran, CA 90001 - Unit 1B
- 1234 Ashton Lane San Fran, CA 90001 - Unit 1C
- 6485 Johnson Lane San Fran, CA 54678

Thanks all, for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what left joins are for.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_properties LEFT JOIN tbl_units ON propertyID=tbl_properties.id
```